# NativeScript WebSocket Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nativescript-websockets'

Tags: android, angular, websocket, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have Angular Web application which I want to run as an Android app, using NativeScript.

For the websocket to work on Android, I'm using [nativescript-websockets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-websockets)

```
tns plugin add nativescript-websockets
```

This works on the Android app.

```
require("nativescript-websockets");

this.websocket = new WebSocket("myUrl, "myProtocol");
```

I've added the above in a service which creates a websocket to the server.

But when I'm trying the run for web, I get the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nativescript-websockets'

When I remove `require("nativescript-websockets");` from the service, it works for web.

What changes would I need such that it works for both Web and Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `nativescript-websockets` on the web part of your application. Since the `nativescript-websockets` package supports the browser based interface your solution could look pretty simple

1. Create a base class of a service that is based on a general websockets interface. This could be a real or an abstract class - depends on your needs.

```js
// services/price-provider.base.ts

export class PriceProviderBase {

    private socket: WebSocket;

    createSocket(): void {
        this.socket = new WebSocket('Your url here');
        this.socket.onopen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
        this.socket.onclose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.socket.onmessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this);
        this.socket.onerror = this.handleError.bind(this);
    }

    handleOpen() {
        // Do your stuff here...
    }
    ...
}
```

2. Extend this base implementation as real services that will be used in web and nativescript environments

For web:

```js
// services/price-provider.service.ts

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {PriceProviderBase} from '~/services/price-provider.base';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PriceProviderService extends PriceProviderBase {}
```

For nativescript:

```js
// services/price-provider.service.tns.ts

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {PriceProviderBase} from '~/services/price-provider.base';

require('nativescript-websockets');

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PriceProviderService extends PriceProviderBase {}
```

If the logic on web and nativescript apps is the same, the only difference in these two implementations will be `require('nativescript-websockets');` line.